# Pulling a timestamp across a database link from postgres to oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, dblink, enterprisedb

The company I work for is in the process of switching from oracle to EnterpriseDB and I'm trying to update a query that uses a timestamp from a table, but whenever I try to pull that timestamp it gives me:

```
[Devart][ODBC][PostgreSQL]Invalid TIMESTAMP string {HY000}
```

I've tried casting it as varchar2, date, timestamp, using to_date, and nothing has worked.

The query is:

```
select "ship_date" from "promotion"@pgProd
```

In postgres ship_date is just a timestamp.

Any information about how this can be accomplished would be appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, this query is being run in oracle pulling data from postgres.

Oracle version is 11g

The relevent line of the creation script is:

```
ship_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
```

Comment: provide ddl for the table you are trying to query.  also, it is unclear if you are on Postgres trying to query oracle or on oracle trying to query postgres.   what version of Oracle?